# Select a parent and all children given the ID of either a parent or a child

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a single table that allows a parent row to have multiple children:

```
ID    ParentID    Name
1     NULL        'I am the parent'
2     1           'I am a child'
3     1           'I am another child'
4     NULL        'I am a loner'
```

I'm looking for the simplest, most efficient way to return all rows in a "family" from any given ID in that "family". If given 1, 2, or 3 the first three rows would be returned, and if given 4 only the final row would be returned*.

I'd love to make this a single SQL call if reasonable (or some sort of stored procedure), as this will be called quite often.

My best attempt has led to multiple calls:

```sql
SELECT ParentID FROM Person WHERE ID = @id

/*if (parentid == null)*/
    SELECT * FROM Person WHERE ID = @id OR ParentID = @id
/*else*/
    SELECT * FROM Person WHERE ID = @parentid OR ParentID = @parentid
```

**A parent cannot itself have a parent, so no recursion should be needed.*

Comment: What was wrong with your second query? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5f39c/2/0 It seems to return what you want.

Comment: @TimSchmelter because all three rows need to be returned if @id=2 or @id=3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need these `OR`s to find your family:

```
SELECT * FROM Person WHERE ID = @id 
OR ParentID = @id 
OR ID = (SELECT ParentID FROM Person p2
         WHERE ID = @id)
OR ParentID = (SELECT ParentID FROM Person p2
         WHERE ID = @id)
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/449d0/1)</kbd>

Comment: You can get rid of the duplicated Subquery by using `IN (Id, ParentID)` http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5f39c/16 I know that's a weird usage of in

Comment: @ConradFrix: Thanks, interesting. I haven't used `IN` in this way before. However, i still prefer the sub queries. All the more  since SQL-Server will (hopefully) optimize them out.